# Getting matching result using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I need to find the matching result i.e a string using Regex. Let me demonstrate the scenario using sample inputs.

```
string input= "xb-cv_107_20190608_032214_006";          // <-1st case
string input = "yb-ha_107_20190608_032214_006__foobar"; // <-2nd case
string input= "fv_vgf_ka01mq3286__20190426_084135_039"; // <-3rd case
string input="fv_vgf_ka01mq3286__2090426_084135_039"; //<-4th case
```

For 1st case input, output required= "xb-cv_107_20190608_032214_006".
For 2nd case input, output required= "yb-ha_107_20190608_032214_006".
For 3rd case input, output required= "fv_vgf_ka01mq3286__20190426_084135_039".
For 4th case input, output required= null since the pattern does not match.

The procedure to get the output is:

- Check using regex if pattern ends with `_` followed by 8 decimals followed by '_' 
  followed by 6 decimals followed by 3 decimals
- Or check using regex if pattern ends with `_` followed by 8 decimals followed by `_` followed  by 6 decimals followed by 3 decimals exists followed by `__` exists followed by anything random.

Till now, I have come up with this Regex expression:

```
string pattern = @".+[_][0-9]{8}[_][0-9]{6}[_][0-9]{3}([_]{2})?";
var result = Regex.Match(input, pattern)?.Groups[0].Value ;
```

Comment: Well no..Ouput comes after ignoring the part after __  if it exists else it is same as input

Comment: It seems you need `var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"^(.+_[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{6}_[0-9]{3})__.*$", "$1");`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it works thanks..May you can add as an answer to this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
var result = Regex.Match(input, @"^(.+_[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{6}_[0-9]{3})__")?.Groups[1].Value;
```

**Regex details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(` - Group 1 start:

  - `.+`  - any 1+ chars other than LF, as many as possible
  - `_[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{6}_[0-9]{3}` - `_`, 8 digits, `_`, 6 digits, `_`, 3 digits
- `)` - end of Group 1
- `__` - two underscores.

If there is a match, the `result` holds the value that resides in Group 1.

If there is no match, `result` is *null*.

Comment: Since you are using Regex.Replace ;is there any way to confirm that match of input and pattern is successful. I need to replace with "null" if the match is not successful.

Comment: Sorry,but this won't help because the result is same in both scenarios:1) The input did not match the pattern 2) The input completely matches the pattern

Comment: Just for example,when   input="lb-aa_107_20190608_32214_006" result will be same as input.

Comment: @user11708636 Ok, that was your question requirement. Now, you ask for something else, now  you want to simply *extract* the value. Just use `var result = Regex.Match(input, @"^(.+_[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{6}_[0-9]{3})__")?.Groups[1].Value;`

Comment: Yeah thanks,sorry for the confusion..may be you can edit the answer.I will mark it as correct for others to be helpful.

Comment: Yeah thanks for the correction..I have edited the question.May be you could edit the answer as well.

Comment: yep..was busy updating question and comments..my fault..Thanks Wiktor